# SQL-How to Sum Data of Clients Over Time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Goal: SUM/AVG Client Data over multiple dates/transactions.
Detailed Question: How do I properly Group clients ('PlayerID') then SUM the int(MinsPlayed), then AVG (AvgBet)?
Current Issue: my Results are giving individual transactions day by day over the 90 day time period instead of the SUM/AVG over the 90 days.

[Current Script/Results: FirstName-Riley is showing each individual daily transaction instead of 1 total SUM/AVG over set time period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzUKj.jpg)

Comment: Do not group by TimePlayed, CashIn, PlayerSkill, PlayerSpeed. These are in your SUMs and don't need to be grouped by, but if you do group by them, then you'll get an individual sum for each individual combination of those (with the other columns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to use DISTINCT as you are going to be aggregating the results using GROUP BY, so you can take that out.

The reason you are returning a row for each transaction is that your GROUP BY clause includes the column you are trying to aggregate (e.g. TimePlayed). Typically, you only want to GROUP BY the columns that are *not* being aggregated, so remove all the columns from the GROUP BY clause that you are aggregating using SUM or AVG (TimePlayed, PlayerSkill etc.).

Comment: Thank You - Very Helpful

Comment: Hi @DataBase, welcome to Stack Overflow. If one of the responses does answer your question, please mark it as the answer - this helps anyone else who looks at this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your current SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CDS_StatDetail.PlayerID, 
    StatType,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Email,
    SUM(TimePlayed)/60 AS MinsPlayed,
    SUM(CashIn) AS AvgBet,
    SUM(PlayerSkill) AS AvgSkillRating,
    SUM(PlayerSpeed) AS Speed,
    CustomFlag1
FROM CDS_Player INNER JOIN CDS_StatDetail
ON CDS_Player.Player_ID = CDS_StatDetail.PlayerID
WHERE StatType='PIT' AND CDS_StatDetail.GamingDate >= '1/02/17' and CDS_StatDetail.GamingDate <= '4/02/2017' AND CustomFlag1='N'
GROUP BY CDS_StatDetail.PlayerID, StatType, FirstName, LastName, Email, TimePlayed, CashIn, PlayerSkill, PlayerSpeed, CustomFlag1
ORDER BY CDS_StatDetail.PlayerID
```

You want something like:

```
SELECT CDS_StatDetail.PlayerID, 
    SUM(TimePlayed)/60 AS MinsPlayed,
    AVG(CashIn) AS AvgBet,
    AVG(PlayerSkill) AS AvgSkillRating,
    SUM(PlayerSpeed) AS Speed,
FROM CDS_Player INNER JOIN CDS_StatDetail
ON CDS_Player.Player_ID = CDS_StatDetail.PlayerID
WHERE StatType='PIT' AND CDS_StatDetail.GamingDate BETWEEN '2017-01-02' AND '2017-04-02' AND CustomFlag1='N'
GROUP BY CDS_StatDetail.PlayerID
```

Next time, please copy and paste your text, not just linking to a screenshot.

Comment: Greatly Appreciated